# Java native library System.loadLibrary fails with UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: java, c++, native

I'm trying to use a native C++ library in Java.

When I'm loading it with

```
System.loadLibrary(filename);
```

I get the error:

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
>   Directory separator should not appear
>   in library name: C:\HelloWorld.dll

Any ideas how I can solve this?

Comment: More generic howto: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14997343/how-to-call-external-dll-function-from-java-code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use:

```
System.loadLibrary("HelloWorld"); // without c:\ and without ".dll" extension
```

Also, make sure `HelloWorld.dll` is available on your library path.

Comment: ok, I'm trying it without C: and I am getting ther error: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no HelloWorld.dll in java.library.path. How do I set the native path? I tried it in the properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries, but its not working

Answer (score 4):

loadLibrary needs the filename without the path and the extension.

If you wanna use the full path, you can try the System.load() method.

See [java.lang.System API](http://docs.cs.uct.ac.za/java2/api/java/lang/System.html#load(java.lang.String)).

Answer (score 0):

I used JNA to do that...

JNA is a simple way to call Native functions it provide NativeLibrary class useful to accomplish this task:

//Java code to call a native function

```
dll = NativeLibrary.getInstance(Mydll);

Function proxy;

proxy = dll.getFunction(Utils.getMethods().get("MyMethodEntryPoint"));
        byte result[] = new byte[256];
        int maxLen = 250;
        String strVer = "";
        Object[] par = new Object[]{result, maxLen};
        intRet = (Integer) proxy.invoke(Integer.class, par);
        if (intRet == 0) {
            strVer = Utils.byteToString(result);
        }
```

you can find documentation at http://jna.java.net/

Answer (score -1):

Surprisingly, the following can be used as well:

```
    final File dll = new File("src/lib/Tester32.dll");

    Test32 test32 = (Test32) Native.loadLibrary(dll.getAbsolutePath(), Test32.class);

    System.out.println(test32.toString() + " - " + test32.GetLastError());
```

It outputs:

```
Proxy interface to Native Library <C:\workspace\jna\src\lib\Tester32.dll@387842048> - 0
```

Javadoc says:

> loadLibrary
>
> public static Object
>   loadLibrary(String name,
>                                    Class interfaceClass)
>
> Map a library interface to the given
>   shared library, providing the explicit
>   interface class. If name is null,
>   attempts to map onto the current
>   process.

If I rename `Tester32.dll` in `.\src\lib`  folder to something else, following exception will occur:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable
>   to load library
>   'C:\workspace\jna\src\lib\Tester32.dll':
>   The specified module could not be
>   found.